# Parsing XML string with python

Tags: python, xml, string

I have an XML string that I take from a wsdl web service. I tried to parse it with elementTree but it is only for files. I tried to save it in a file in order to parse it but it says I don't have permission to open the file. So I used this solution that I found in stackoverflow:

```
try:
        queryresult = client.service.executeQuery(query)
except WebFault, e:
        print e

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(queryresult))
rootElem = tree.getroot()
result = rootElem.findall(".//result")
```

but when I print the result I take a value like Element 'result' at 0x7f6e454bdb90

I also tried to print

```
result.text
```

or

```
 for s in result:
    test =  s.attrib
```

and in result = rootElem.findall(".//result") i also tried result = rootElem.findall("result") or result = rootElem.findall("results/result")

This is the xml string (I added only a part of it because it is too big):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sparql> <head> <variable name="id"/> <variable name="code"/> <variable name="title"/> <variable name="text"/> <variable name="substanceCode"/> <variable name="patientId"/> <variable name="birthTime"/> <variable name="effectiveTime_start"/> </head> <results> <result> <binding name="id"> <literal>df868fff-9d48-11e2-8ee8-833b8491ffe6</literal> </binding> <binding name="code"> <literal>432102000</literal> </binding> <binding name="title"> <literal>Administration of substance (procedure)</literal> </binding> <binding name="text"> <literal>Aclarubicin (product)</literal> </binding> <binding name="substanceCode"> <literal>326830005</literal> </binding> <binding name="patientId"> <literal>fictitious1</literal> </binding> <binding name="birthTime"> <literal>1965-03-01T00:00:00.0</literal> </binding> </result>
```

I also tried @alecxe solution:

```
def index(request,requestresult): 
   data = requestresult
   tree = ET.fromstring(data) 
   for literal in tree.findall('.//result/binding/literal') 
      returnresult = literal.text 
   if tokens_p(request): 
      account_id = urllib.unquote(request.session['oauth_token_set']['account_id'])  
      return utils.render_template('ui/index', { 'ACCOUNT_ID': account_id, 'SETTINGS': settings,'returnresult':returnresult}) 
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))
```

And then I printed the results {{returnresult}} in index.html but nothing is printing. 
Then I tried:

```
tree =  ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))
rootElem = tree.getroot()
returnresult = rootElem.findall('.//results/result/binding/literal')
```

and it prints Element 'literal' at 0x7f6e4529fc10 Element 'literal' at 0x7f6e4529fc90 etc. And when I try to print it with:

```
 for literal in rootElem.findall('.//results/result/binding/literal')
     returnresult = literal.text
```

I have an error invalid syntax in line: "for literal in rootElem.findall('.//results/result/binding/literal')"

Comment: What do you need to get from the `result` nodes?

Comment: the value (for example Aclarubicin) in field <binding name="text">. But when I put findall(.//text) nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you want to get the value of `literal` tag inside `binding` tag that is inside `result`. In this case you should use `.//result/binding/literal` xpath expression:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sparql>
    <head>
        <variable name="id"/>
        <variable name="code"/>
        <variable name="title"/>
        <variable name="text"/>
        <variable name="substanceCode"/>
        <variable name="patientId"/>
        <variable name="birthTime"/>
        <variable name="effectiveTime_start"/>
    </head>
    <results>
    <result>
        <binding name="id">
            <literal>df868fff-9d48-11e2-8ee8-833b8491ffe6</literal>
        </binding>
        <binding name="code">
            <literal>432102000</literal>
        </binding>
    </result>
    </results>
</sparql>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

print [literal.text for literal in tree.findall('.//result/binding/literal')]
```

prints:

```
['df868fff-9d48-11e2-8ee8-833b8491ffe6', '432102000']
```

Note I've cut down xml a bit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn't print anything. If you haven't cut down the xml it would also print the value of the <variable name="text"/>?

Comment: @user1431148 not sure what the problem is. Could you provide the code you are running? (I'd try the whole xml)

Comment: def index(request,requestresult):
     data = requestresult
     tree = ET.fromstring(data)
     for literal in tree.findall('.//result/binding/literal')
       returnresult = literal.text
     if tokens_p(request):
       account_id = urllib.unquote(request.session['oauth_token_set']['account_id'])
       return utils.render_template('ui/index', { 'ACCOUNT_ID': account_id,
                                                    'SETTINGS': settings,'returnresult':returnresult})
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))

Comment: And then I print {{returnresult}} in index.html to see if I get results. But nothing prints

Comment: It would be good to see what is passed to the view in `requestresult` variable.

Comment: @user1431148 You should update your question with a formatted version of the code you posted above.

Comment: Ok I found the error and your solution works! thank you!